# Наибольшая общая подстрока

Tags: c, строки, алгоритм

Я решаю задачу поиска наибольшей общей подстроки. Я использую функцию, опубликованную здесь: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/

Вот она:

```
int LCSubStr(char *X, char *Y, int m, int n)
{
    int LCSuff[m+1][n+1];
    int result = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                LCSuff[i][j] = 0;

            else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
            {
                LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                result = max(result, LCSuff[i][j]);
            }
            else LCSuff[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Об этой задаче есть статья в Википедии. Некоторые вещи описаны в статьях:

- [Английская Википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)
- [Русская Википедия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

В общем, в результате работы получается двумерный массив, максимальный элемент которого и обозначает длину наибольшей общей подстроки

Пример:

```
    SUBSEQUENCE
   000000000000
 S 010010000000
 U 002000010000
 B 000300000000
 E 000001001001
 U 001000010000
 E 000001002001
 N 000000000300
 C 000000000040
 S 010010000000
```

Длина наибольшей общей подстроки: 4

**Как я могу получить саму подстроку?** (например, в виде позиции вхождения в первую или вторую строки). Мне нужен не код, а алгоритм хотя бы. Как это математически высчитывается. У меня были догадки, но это всего лишь догадки.

Comment: Алгоритм вроде как очевидный:
- находится максимальное число в массиве;
- координаты числа - позиция последнего(!) символа наибольшей совпавшей последовательности;
- для получения начала вхождения просто отнять от координат это самое число;
- ну и для получения самой совпавшей строки можно вырезать из любой исходной строки символы слева, от полученной координаты с длиной этого максимального числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать плохой понятный алгоритм, чем хороший, но в котором Вы не разобрались. Вот неэффективно, зато интуитивно - http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1127343.html